# implement bash command cd in perl

Tags: perl, bash

I tried to implement a bash command `system("cd /home/user")` in perl , but I get an error saying

```
Can't exec "cd": No such file or directory at temp.pl
```

Is there a way to change the current working directory to the specified one , and the change remains after the perl script has exited also.

Comment: No it is not possible, and almost certainly you're chasing solution to XY problem.

Answer (score 6):

No. A process can't change its parent process's current working directory. Shells implement commands like `cd` as "builtins", meaning they're a function in the shell itself, and not a separate process that gets run.

You can change the current directory in perl using `chdir($dir)`, and that change will be inherited by child processes — but it won't be passed along to the parent process.

Answer (score 4):

When you want to change the directory inside your Script, you can use the Perl command `chdir('dir')`

Example:

```
chdir($dir);
```

You actually cant modify the directory of the parents process, but you can of the current process

Answer (score 3):

You cannot modify the current working directory of a different process in UNIX, at least not without some serious hackery.

This is why `cd` is a built-in in all shells. It is not an external program (nor can it be implemented as an external program).

Answer (score 3):

`cd` is not a process, it is a shell builtin command that changes the current working directory for that shell process.

So use `system("sh -c 'cd /my/dir'")`. but here system command itself invoke another shall so still it not change directory.

use [chdir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chdir.html) for that.

Answer (score 2):

`cd` is not a process, it is a **shell builtin command** that changes the current working directory for that shell process. So **system("sh -c 'cd /cat/bat'") would "succeed"**, but still wouldn't change the working directory of your perl process; use **chdir** for that.